# docker cmd in bash whileloop with grep

Tags: bash, docker, while-loop

Hi i want to use a simple "healthcheck" for docker in bash like this:

```
while ["$(docker exec -it ${mysql_name} mysql -u${mysql_user} -p${mysql_user_password} -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | grep ${mysql_name})" != ${mysql_name}]
do
   sleep 1
   echo "waiting for database..."
done
```

but i only get "*mysql/test.sh: line 21: $'| nextcloud_db       |\r': command not found*". So it seems like bash is trying to output grep and I have no idea :(

"*| nextcloud_db       |*" ist the output of the cmd in while

the single docker cmd + grep works

edit: maybe its better to check if grep is true? (and not this "!= ${mysql_name}"(btw. this will not working i guess, its not " string is not equal to var" its "string contains var"))

Comment: I also anticipate the same. Try in a single expression maybe ?

Comment: okay until helps, its not perfect but it works for now... i will reply the solution later. OMG and i need a whitespace after [ and before ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for other noobs :). Its important to set a whitespace after [ and ] before

```
while [ "$(grep ${mysql_name} <<< $(docker exec ${mysql_name} mysql -u${mysql_user} -p${mysql_user_password} -e 'SHOW DATABASES;'))" != ${mysql_name} ]
do
    echo "waiting for database..."
    sleep 5
done
```

its not perfect, because i get the first line of the docker cmd output (mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.) but it works for me (I hate that I said that...)

edit: the "" in the while are necessary to work correct?!

Comment: You could also use grep's exit status: `while grep -q hello <<< hello; do echo found; sleep 1; done`

Comment: @Cole Tierney thx, that's better! But the main problem was the brackets and spaces ... but I didn't find the problem and saw no choice but to ask